# Microwave effect

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, power, biology, microwaves

I'm new to the forum. I state that I am a technician and I have to deal every day, even with various types of radar, but I am not only concerned with this. I found out on the web about the danger of microwaves, as they can heat the bones of the skull or the inner ear, as in the case of the Frey effect. I would like to know through your help at what power levels expressed in Watts these severe symptoms occur so that I cannot reach them. Through calculations with dBm (Decibel milliwatt) I have reached about 200 watts of power but I'm not sure if these are the correct formulas, could you help me?

Comment: You have to be more specific - how close to the source are you? How long are you exposed? Very long exposure _and_  very close proximity to a radar emitter are usually required for any significant injury.

Comment: Ho joseph the distance us between 10 and 20 metres, and the time is about a few seconds

Comment: You should be able to get what you need to know from the FDA website.

Comment: I tried but I can't get any details about the internal structure of the human body

Comment: Every radar I've worked with or have seen has a "stay back xxxx (feet)" when in operation sign when in a testing configuration. Where 'xxxx' ranged from one meter for a Mars landing radar, to 500 feet for something on the underbelly of a global hawk. Any serious lab capable of making these thing should have a safety office.